# How to import GraphQL query as a string instead of an object

Tags: vue.js, graphql, graphql-js, graphql-tag

I created a `.gql` file for my query and I'm importing it like this:

```
const query = require("@/hello.gql");
```

However, if I log the `query` variable to the console, it shows an object, not a string. What can I do so that my imported query is just a string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because, you are only importing the query, not using it.

You can use apollo to use that query like this

```
const yourQuery= require("@/hello.gql");

data(){
 return {
    queryResponse: []  
  }
}

apollo: {
    queryResponse: {
      prefetch: true,
      query: yourQuery
    }
  }
```

Whit this, you are fetch the query and save the response in queryResponse

Answer (score 3):

When querying your server using `apollo-client`, the provided `query` parameter has to be an object of the type `DocumentNode`, which is an AST representation of the query. In other words, if you use `apollo-client`, you can't just pass it a query as a string, you have to parse it first. This is commonly done using the `graphql-tag` library. It can *also* be done automatically through webpack by utilizing a loader like `graphql-tag`'s loader or `graphql-loader`. If you utilize a loader like that, then any `.gql` files you import will automatically be parsed into `DocumentNode` objects for you.

If you're *not* using `apollo-client`, there's no need to utilize those loaders. If you still want to store you queries in separate files and import them as strings, you should utilize a different loader, for example, [raw-loader](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/raw-loader).

Answer (score 0):

Now raw-loader is deprecated, you can load them like this.

In the webpack config

```
 module: {
  rules: [
    {
      test: /\.gql/,
      type: "asset/source",
    },
  ],
},
```

Then import

```
import myGraphQlQuery from "myGraphQlQuery.gql"
```

Comment: If the "test" property is matching any .gql files other that the intended target, then there may be unintended consequences, depending on what OP is ultimately trying to achieve.